# Inject values into field from properties files using field name as a key

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, guice

In guice you have the possibillity to use the `@Named` annotation to inject values from property files into class fields.

```java
@Inject
@Named("nameLengthMin")
private int nameLengthMin;
```

I want to build a version of the `@Named` annotation that does not need a key parameter, but instead uses the field name as a key to search in the property file.

```java
// takes field name as key
@Inject
@Named
private int nameLengthMin;
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can achieve this using guice, but I'm pretty new to guice and writing my own annotations.

How do I write an annotation that can give me the annotated field as a parameter?

Comment: I don't think you can as Java annotations don't have a link back to the think that they are attached to.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by using custom injections, see https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections.

If you use Inject and Named, you have to deal with guice's internal implementation, so I would suggest creating a custom "InjectProperty" binding annotation (like  InjectLogger). Then you can follow the example and your "PropertyMembersInjector" can read properties and check if the field name is a valid key and then cast/transform the property value and set it on the field.
It will be some coding, but its doable.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm digging up an old thread, but I wanted to share my findings with other other people Googling this.

This functionality has been [requested](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/62) quite a while ago, but it's not supported yet.  The most appropriate annotation for doing this would be [JSR 250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSR_250)'s [@Resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) annotation.  @jan-galinski isn't wrong, but there are third party solutions out there that have already done this work for you.

[GuiceyFruit](https://code.google.com/p/guiceyfruit/) adds this functionality, but it seems to be abandoned (and not all functionality works with Guice 3).  Nonetheless, here is an example of how that could be done

```
@GrabResolver(name='GuiceyFruit', root='http://guiceyfruit.googlecode.com/svn/repo/releases')
@Grab(group='org.guiceyfruit', module='guiceyfruit-spring', version='2.0')
@Grab(group='com.google.inject', module='guice', version='3.0')
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import org.guiceyfruit.spring.SpringModule;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();
        System.out.println("thingOne before injection='"+box.thingOne+"'");
        System.out.println("thingTwo before injection='"+box.thingTwo+"'");
        Guice.createInjector(new SpringModule(), new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("thingOne")).toInstance("THING ONE");
                bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("thingTwo")).toInstance("THING TWO");
            }
        }).injectMembers(box);
        System.out.println("thingOne after injection='"+box.thingOne+"'");
        System.out.println("thingTwo after injection='"+box.thingTwo+"'");
    }

    public static class Box {
        @Resource public String thingOne;
        @Resource public String thingTwo;
    }
}
```

[mycila Guice Extensions](https://github.com/mycila/guice/) is another option (and the one I would recommend since it is still maintained and offers better modularity).  I've [requested](https://github.com/mycila/guice/issues/8) this functionality be added, so that should be available soon.  Once it is, here's how it would be used:

```
@Grab(group='com.google.inject', module='guice', version='3.0')
@Grab(group='com.mycila.guice.extensions', module='mycila-guice-jsr250', version='3.6.ga')
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.mycila.guice.ext.jsr250.Jsr250Module;
import com.mycila.guice.ext.closeable.CloseableModule;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();
        System.out.println("thingOne before injection='"+box.thingOne+"'");
        System.out.println("thingTwo before injection='"+box.thingTwo+"'");
        Guice.createInjector(new Jsr250Module(), new CloseableModule(), new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("thingOne")).toInstance("THING ONE");
                bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("thingTwo")).toInstance("THING TWO");
            }
        }).injectMembers(box);
        System.out.println("thingOne after injection='"+box.thingOne+"'");
        System.out.println("thingTwo after injection='"+box.thingTwo+"'");
    }

    public static class Box {
        @Resource public String thingOne;
        @Resource public String thingTwo;
    }
}
```

Lastly, Netflix's [Governator](https://github.com/Netflix/governator) also supports @Resource wiring, but it's a little clunkier to wire up.  This [unit test](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/blob/master/governator-core/src/test/java/com/netflix/governator/lifecycle/resources/TestResources.java) looked like the best example I could find.